# Do I have to reveal the order of cards when I reveal multiple cards simultaneously?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If instructed to reveal the top multiple cards from my library, do I have to reveal the order they occupied in the library as well?

If not, can I look at the cards in the order they occupied in the library, then mix up the order before showing them to my opponent?

As a concrete example, could I resolve [Epiphany at the Drownyard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Epiphany%20at%20the%20Drownyard) by (sequentially)...

1. picking up the top X plus one cards of my library
2. deciding what the piles will be
3. mixing up the cards (to reduce the information about my thought process that can be inferred)
4. showing the cards to my opponent and declaring the piles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules don't specifically address this, but logically, the library is an ordered zone, and the revealed cards continue to be in the library, so they continue to have that order, and the opponent should be able to see what that order is.

However, practically speaking, it doesn't really matter. The order doesn't actually matter once the effect completes, and the information that you give up by your choice of piles is going to dwarf any information you give up in the process of choosing those piles.

Comment: I agree that the order probably is revealed as well. When I knew something about the top cards of my library (e.g. scry) before casting this reveal-spell the order might give clues as to what I wanted to have on top (e.g. because I don't have this combo piece but do have the other one). Generally, it does not matter of course.

Comment: Yeah if I play Serum Visions and scry a land to the top, then opponent plays Thought Scour targeting me and see I put a land on top, they could reasonably infer that I have a land-light hand. It often doesn't matter, but it could.

Comment: Honestly if you have done any top deck manipulation then knowing which card you put there could be information since it gives information of what you are looking for.